# Python class inheritance, attributeError

Tags: python, inheritance, state-machine

I wrote a `StateMachine` class in Python so it could be inherited from.
The logic of it work as expected but I can access the Attribute `self.data` from a `State` which is present in the derived `StateMachine` class named `StateMachineTest`.

The following error is generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nbout/work/python/state_machine/main.py", line 68, in 
   main()
File "/home/nbout/work/python/state_machine/main.py", line 59, in main
   test = StateMachineTest()
File "/home/nbout/work/python/state_machine/main.py", line 47, in __init__
   StateMachine.__init__(self, Started())
File "/home/nbout/work/python/state_machine/state_machine.py", line 17, in _init__
   self.current_state.on_enter(self)
File "/home/nbout/work/python/state_machine/main.py", line 16, in on_enter
   print("Started: data:{}".format(sm_test.data))
Started: on_enter
AttributeError: 'StateMachineTest' object has no attribute 'data'
Started: on_exit
```

state_machine.py

```
class State:

    def on_enter(self, state_machine):
        pass

    def on_exit(self, state_machine):
        pass


class StateMachine:

    def __init__(self, start_state):
        self.current_state = start_state

        self.current_state.on_enter(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.current_state.on_exit(self)

    def set_state(self, state):

        self.current_state.on_exit(self)
        self.current_state = state
        self.current_state.on_enter(self)
```

main.py

```
from state_machine import StateMachine
from state_machine import State


class StateTest(State):
    def pause(self, state_machine_test):
        pass

    def start(self, state_machine_test):
        pass


class Started(StateTest):
    def on_enter(self, sm_test):
        print("Started: on_enter")
        print("Started: data:{}".format(sm_test.data))

    def on_exit(self, sm_test):
        print("Started: on_exit")

    def pause(self, sm_test):
        print("Started: pause")
        sm_test.set_state(Paused())

    def start(self, sm_test):
        print("Started: start")


class Paused(StateTest):
    def on_enter(self, sm_test):
        print("Paused: on_enter")

    def on_exit(self, sm_test):
        print("Paused: on_exit")

    def pause(self, sm_test):
        print("Paused: pause")

    def start(self, sm_test):
        print("Paused: start")
        sm_test.set_state(Started())


class StateMachineTest(StateMachine):

    def __init__(self):
        StateMachine.__init__(self, Started())
        self.data = 10

    def pause(self):
        self.current_state.pause(self)

    def start(self):
        self.current_state.start(self)


def main():

    test = StateMachineTest()

    test.start()
    test.pause()
    test.pause()
    test.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that `StateMachine.__init__(self, Started())` requires `self`'s `data` atttribute to already be set, but you only set it the next line (`self.data = 10`). Switch these two lines around and try again!

Comment: This is the solution, thanks. I will Accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow let me...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this code is really unnecessarily complicated.

The problem appears to be that you initialise `Started` in the `__init__` of your StateMachineTest class, so that its `on_enter` runs before you have set `self.data`.

You might be able fix this by moving the assignment of `self.data` above the `super` call, but a much better bet would be to simplify your inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. I used inheritance that way to enforced reusability of the `StateMachine` class